# Гостиный/гостинный

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, нн

Слово *гостиный* можно только в словосочетании *гостиный двор* писать?

В остальных случаях надо писать ***гостинный***: *гостинный диван, гостинный сад, гостинная обстановка, гостинная кухня, гостинный ковёр, костинный стаканы*?

Или если что-то для гостей, то мы пишем ***гостиный***, то бишь *гостиный бокал, гостиная комната, гостиный сад, гостиный ковёр, гостиная вилка, гостиное шампанское*; а если что-то принадлежит гостиной комнате, то мы пишем ***гостинный***, то есть *гостинный свет, гостинная ваза, гостинный кот, гостинные стены, гостинные часы-маятник*?

Comment: В орфографическом словаре Лопатина одно н.

Answer (score 1):

> ГОСТИНЫЙ [нн], гостиная, гостиное. Только в выражении:
> гостиный двор - торговые ряды в обособленном городском или
> общественном здании. (первонач. прил. к гость в знач. иностранный
> купец.) Толковый словарь Ушакова.

> Гост'иный Дв'ор (архит. Памятник; универмаг в нек-рых городах) Русский орфографический словарь.

[Сказка об Иване-гостином сыне](https://www.sites.google.com/site/russkieskazki/home/russkie/skazka-ob-ivane-gostinom-syne) (1794-1795)

Гостиный - принадлежащий гостю или гостям.

[Гости́ный](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD*%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x&help=1#:%7E:text=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20(%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%3A%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%2C%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%3B%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%2C%20%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)) (от гость: гостиный ряд, двор; гостиный корпус, флигель). Грамота ру.

Для гостей не подходит, потому что это было связано не с вещами, а с происхождением или местом. Гостиный корпус/флигель - стал гостиничным, гостиницей или гостевым; гостиный ряд - это место закрепленное за гостями-купцами; гостиный сын - это происходящий от любовника, гостя, не хозяина. Гостиная - место в доме, зал, где принимали гостей. Логика "для" тут видимо не работает.

Гостиный - притяжательное прилагательное, суффикс ИН, отвечает на вопрос не какой? а чей? как я уже писал в другом вопросе про "говядинный". - Чей сын? - Гостиный. Чья зала? - Гостиная. А это чья? - Хозяйская.

Можно ли к чему-то еще придумать прилагательное гостиный? Может быть и можно, гостиный день?

> — Полинька! Вот гостиный день у меня неожиданно. — А вы отшельницей живете, скрываетесь. Лесков.

Если постараться, то можно, но это вряд ли будут вещи, либо какие-то особые вещи. Хотя про вещи говорят гостевые: гостевые бокалы, гостевое постельное бельё.

Гостиный - это тот, что не хозяйский, где хозяин это гость.

Но слов не так много, новые пока не придумали, потому что отношение к миру поменялось.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что по последней ссылке есть следующее: "гости**нн**ый (от гостиная: гости**нн**ая мебель, гости**нн**ый завсегдатай)".

Comment: гостиный (от гость: гостиный ряд, двор; гостиный корпус, флигель) - Там же чуть ниже.

Comment: Это я видел, конечно. Но вопрос-то касается и двух Н. Вы отмечаете только одну информацию и игнорируете другую.

Comment: Я вроде написал, то что принадлежит гостям, а не "от гостей".  Ладно, щас попробую сформулировать еще раз.

Comment: Нет от гостиной, есть от гостей. Гостиная тоже от гостей.) Ну с двумя НН все остальное будет.

Comment: Вот я и говорю: даёте ссылку, где есть и то, и другое, а упор делаете только на одно.

Comment: Потому что логика есть только в том, чтобы определить когда одна Н, во всех остальных случаях две НН. Одна Н всего в нескольких выражениях есть, так сейчас не говорят, можно постараться придумать, но вещи будут писаться скорее всего с НН

Comment: С одной Н могут писаться топонимы, места, может время какое-то, ну еще родство, если ребенок ублюдок). Теоретически еще можно сказать чей подарок - гостиный. В смысле не от родственника, а от гостя - стороннего человека, но я не уверен.

Comment: Это Лесков только мог такое выдумывать, потому что он виртуоз слова: "В первой комнате с диваном и двумя большими зеркалами у него был гостиный покой, а во второй он устроил себе кабинет и спальню." А в том же словаре Ушакова только одно словосочетание - это гостиный двор.

Comment: *Гостиный — притяжательное местоимение...* Может, прилагательное?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова да, спасибо, именно его я имел ввиду)

Comment: Нет слова "гостинный", оно есть только в словаре, или же устарело. Орфографический редактор исправил ошибку, а на ресурсе "Карта слов" нет таких примеров.  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/гостиный+двор    https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/гостиная

Comment: «Прочел я «Le Moqueur amoureux» S. Gay: слабо, жидко, но довольно хорошо, роман гостинный») да можно употребить, если к месту будет, ничего криминального или ради хохмы.

Comment: На "Карте слов" есть всё: и само слово "гостинный" со ссылкой на академический сооварь, и предложения с этим словом.

Comment: А ссылка? Можно привести, там и предложения увидим. А в  современном языке используется это слово?  У нас вроде бы есть только дизайн гостиной и набор мебели для гостиной. Или еще что-нибудь есть?

Comment: гостинный роман - роман, состоящий из гостинных.

Comment: https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словом/гостинный   https://kartaslov.ru/как-правильно-пишется-слово/гостинный

Comment: Убранство комнаты не зальное и не гостинное, а и то и другое вместе. Лесков