# Гостиный/гостинный. Как правильно?

Tags: орфография

Слово *гостиный* можно только в словосочетании *гостиный двор* писать?

В остальных случаях надо писать *гостинный*: *гостинный диван, гостинный сад, гостинная обстановка, гостинная кухня, гостинный ковёр, гостинный стаканы*?

Или если что-то для гостей, то мы пишем *гостиный*, то бишь *гостиный бокал, гостиная комната, гостиный сад, гостиный ковёр, гостиная вилка, гостиное шампанское*; а если что-то принадлежит гостиной комнате, то мы пишем *гостинный*, то есть *гостинный свет, гостинная ваза, гостинный кот, гостинные стены, гостинные часы-маятник*?

Comment: Дубляж вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475415/Гостиный-гостинный